# How to select all text excluding a single node using XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Given the following XML:

```
<div class="a">
    some text i want to see
    <div class="b">
        other text i want to see
    <div>
    <div class="c">
        some text i DON'T WANT to see
    </div>  
    some more text i wish to see..
</div>
```

I would like to have an XPATH that selects all the text that is not under class `c`.

Expected output:

```
some text i want to see
other text i want to see
some more text i wish to see..
```

Comment: Share your current XPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[@class="a"]//text()[not(parent::div[@class="c"])]
```

will select all text nodes without a `div` parent of `@class="c"`:

```
some text i want to see
other text i want to see

some more text i wish to see..
```

If you want to exclude white-space-only text nodes, then this XPath,

```
//div[@class="a"]//text()[not(parent::div[@class="c"]) and normalize-space()]
```

will select these text nodes,

```
some text i want to see
other text i want to see
some more text i wish to see..
```

as requested.